# SageMaker DataWrangler's one-hot-encoding into vector convert into suitable form using pandas

Tags: pandas, amazon-sagemaker

Using SageMaker DataWrangler's one-hot-encoding I have a column whose datapoints are of form

```
"(26,[2],[1.0])"
"(26,[0],[1.0])"
```

how can I convert into suitable form using pandas to train a model

Answer (score 0):

The one-hot encoder let’s you output the encoding as columns instead of a vector. When you go to one-hot encode, there should be an option called “Output style”. If you select column (and not vector), you will get the data representation you are looking for.